# What's the best way to replicate the functionality of a Windows Explorer folder UI in WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows, user-interface, windows-explorer

So I'm using `FileSystemWatcher` to populate and update a playlist. I want to replicate many features of Windows Explorer, most importantly:
* inline rename
* slow double click to rename

I'm having quite a hassle doing this, so I thought, maybe there's an easier way than reimplementing the wheel? Maybe I can somehow host a Windows Explorer window in my application as a control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosting a real Windows Explorer window in your application is possible but fraught with peril:  The techniques are different in XP vs Vista vs Win7 and you will be dealing with all sorts of low-level stuff.  I would strongly recommend against trying it.

I think your best options are:

1. Use Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog if it can be easily adapted to your need, or
2. Code your own functionality, or if you are very brave:
3. Launch a separate Explorer window, optionally with code that tries to force its position and size to be over your application (this too is hard...)

**Notes on inline rename feature**

The inline rename and slow double-click to rename features are really quite trivial to implement.

In your view model add:

- A "NewName" string DependencyProperty
- A "Renaming" bool DependencyProperty with a PropertyChangedCallback.  When "Renaming" goes true, copy Name to NewName.  When it goes false, if NewName!=Name rename the file an update Name.

In your DataTemplate add a trigger on "Renaming" that replaces your TextBlock bound to "Name" with a TextBox bound to "NewName".

Add these event handlers:
* KeyDown event:  If F2 is pressed toggle Renaming.  If Enter is pressed and Renaming, set Renaming=false.  If Esc is pressed and Renaming copy Name to NewName and set Renaming=false.
* LostFocus event:  Set Renaming=false
* SelectionChanged event on container:  Record timestamp of last selection change.
* MouseDown event:  If left click and selection changed > 0.5 seconds ago, set Renaming = true

Many other features of Explorer view are similarly easy to implement, such as grouping and multiple columns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The hard part of inline rename is all those small things like the edit box stretching across multiple columns to accommodate the text but not over the edge of the `ListView`.

Comment: You can use an Adorner to solve this.  Create the Adorner, bind its DataContext and add it to the AdornerLayer using an attached property set by the trigger.  Use a ControlTemplate instantiate the TextBox in the Adorner.  In your adorner's MeasureOverride, search up the visual tree of its target for the first containing ListView, TransformToDescendant its right-hand edge, and subtract to get the the proper width.  Use the child's height.  In ArrangeOverride redo the same computation and InvalidateMeasure() if it has changed.

Comment: But Adorner doesn't support templating.

Comment: True. This means you will need a `Control` inside your `Adorner`. I derive most of my adorners from a small class I wrote which creates a `Control` in the constructor and binds its `Template` property to a locally `AddOwnered` "Template" property and stores it in a field, then overrides `VisualChildrenCount` to return 1 and `GetVisualChild()` to return the Control. This allows templating to be easily used with adorners. Note that the `Control` I use is constructed with `new Control()`, in other words it is not a subclass of `Control`.

Comment: The binding to the `AddOwnered` property is like this: `_control.SetBinding(TemplateProperty, new Binding("Template") { Source = this });`

Comment: I managed this with a `ContentPresenter` and a `DataTemplate`. The `TextBox` shows up alright, but it's transparent to mouse clicks. What now? By the way, I appreciate you walking me through this.